# Maths olympiad of class 10

Tags: mathematics

How many 6digit numbers of the form  XYZZYX (where Y is prime) are possible which are divisible by 7

A 42
B 56
C 70
D 84

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?

Answer (score 2):

$100001 x + 10010 y + 1100 z \equiv 0 \mod 7$

$6 x + z \equiv 0 \mod 7$

It is easy to go through the $x$ values from 1 to 9 and see if there are two (or just one) corresponding $z$ values. There are a total of 14 possible $(x, z)$ pairs, and $4$ possible prime $y$ values. So, the final answer is $14 \times 4 = 56$.

Comment: $6 x + z \equiv 0 \mod 7$  means  $z \equiv x \mod 7$

Comment: @FlorianF $z \equiv -x$, surely?

Comment: No.  take 6x+y=0, add x on both sides (mod 7) and you get z=x.